# Semaphores : DISPATCH_TIME_NOW vs DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Can somebody please provide me with an example of when you would use DISPATCH_TIME_NOW vs DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER when using semaphores?

What is the difference between the 2 and in what case would  I use one over the other?

According to the docs DISPATCH_TIME_NOW means timeout immediately. DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER means timeout infinity.

Why would you ever want the former, ie: timeout immediately.

Comment: Do you mean DISPATCH_TIME_NOW vs DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER?

Comment: Whoops, Im sorry. That was a typo. Corrected now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can timeout immediately to check if an block has finished computing. Similarly you can wait forever until a block has completed before continuing executing another block.

An example of checking if a group is finished could look like this.

```
if (dispatch_group_wait(myDispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) {
    // myDispatchGroup is finished... 
} else {
    // myDispatchGroup is _not_ finished...
}
```

Checking if a group is finished when waiting forever doesn't make sense since the function is going to wait forever. Instead we use the function to synchronously block (block as in pause or wait, not as in GCD block) until the group is completed.

```
// Enqueue myDispatchGroup

// Wait for it to finish
dispatch_group_wait(myDispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); 

// Do other work that depends on myDispatchGroup being completed
```

Comment: would it be fair to say that DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER is for group creation and that DISPATCH_TIME_NOW is for group querying?

Comment: I wouldn't say group "creation" since a very common thing to wait forever to do is to release the group using `dispatch_release(group);`. I would call it group dependencies.

Comment: The number of situations in which making the call `dispatch_group_wait(myDispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` is the right thing to do is vanishingly small. Most of the time this will block. Blocking the main thread is bad, blocking GCD threads is (potentially) bad.  Use `dispatch_group_notify` to queue up a block to run when your group is finished without blocking the enqueueing thread.